# If initial directory doesn't exist, create it, but if user cancel the save, delete the newly added folders

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

I want to save a textbox text to a .txt file created in a special directory, using a SaveFileDialog.

But let's say my path doesn't exist: I would like that when the dialogbox shows up to ask where the user want to save his .txt file, the dialogbox create automatically the missing folders if they are missing. But I also like that if the user cancel his saving, the newly created folder to erase if they are empty.

In other words: the SaveFileDialog dialogbox shows up in an initial directory, but if this initial directory is null, my code generate this directory BUT if the user cancel, my code erase the generated directory.

Here's my example: I want to save my .txt in Desktop\FolderExistingOrNot, but if the folder FolderExistingOrNot I want to creat it. But if the user cancels, I want to delete if FolderExistingOrNot is empty.

```
private void btn_SAVE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.DefaultExt = "txt";
    sfd.Filter = ".TXT (*.txt)|*.txt";
    sfd.FileName = textBox1.Text;
    sfd.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\FolderExistingOrNot";
    //Directory.CreateDirectory(sfd.InitialDirectory); // could use that but if the user cancel, this folder will not be destroyed
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(sfd.FileName, textBox2.Text);
    }
    else // if the user cancel the saving
    {
        // I would like to erase the folder FolderExistingOrNot if it's empty
    }
}
```

It might be simple but I haven't figured out how to do it.

Comment: The [Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=netframework-4.8) class is what you want.

Comment: I see you've already used it in your code.  [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=netframework-4.8) will tell you if files already exist in the Directory.  [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.delete?view=netframework-4.8) will allow you to delete the empty folder.

Comment: maybe, disable [`CheckFileExists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.checkpathexists?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_FileDialog_CheckPathExists) and just create the directory on `DialogResult.OK`?

Comment: @timur: unfortunatly, this method will open the dialogbox in Documents folder if the path don't exist, but me I would like that it always open in my initial directory
@RobertHarvey: I've put `Directory.Delete(sfd.InitialDirectory);` inside my `else` but I get an exception if the folder is not empty. But I've put the whole thing inside a try catch, not an issue I guess, thanks !

Comment: What if the folder was already there? Do you still want to delete it?

Comment: @Kim: If the folder is empty, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me when I tested it.

```
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.DefaultExt = "txt";
    sfd.Filter = ".TXT (*.txt)|*.txt";
    sfd.FileName = textBox1.Text;

    string mypath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\FolderExistingOrNot";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(mypath);

    sfd.InitialDirectory = mypath;
    //Directory.CreateDirectory(sfd.InitialDirectory); // could use that but if the user cancel, this folder will not be destroyed
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(sfd.FileName, textBox2.Text);
    }
    else // if the user cancel the saving
    {
        if (Directory.GetFiles(mypath).Length == 0)
        {
            Directory.Delete(mypath);
        }
    }
```